# Python PIL: from form file to image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to save an image that is uploaded from a form. Not sure how to do this.

I get the file:

```
photo = request.FILES
```

and have tried various things along the lines of:

```
import cStringIO, PIL
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(photo) )
```

EDIT: It would also be helpful is someone could just shoe me how to get the file saved. It doesn't have to be PIL. Then I can get it from there using PIL.

Comment: You don't need to use PIL if what you want is just save the uploaded file.

Comment: I'll also need to resize it. I have been using PIl for that.

Comment: Will you save the file to model field?

Comment: Yes. I have used Django before, but I don't want to do that for this.